# Laravel 4 ReflectionException error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

exception `'ReflectionException'` with message

```
Class Chrono\Services\Controllers\Frontend\KeywordController does not exist
in /home/legal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:296
```

I am installing a site on liquidweb.com and I am getting the above error.

Has anyone ever gotten this error before?

Comment: What is the full path and filename to your KeywordController controller class file ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to `php composer dump-autoload`
It seems that Laravel can't find this class, and won't initialize it.

Comment: You mean php artisan dump-autoload? With php composer dump-autoload, it says "Could not open input file: composer".

Comment: Do a php composer.phar dump-autoload. Composer will generate a autoloading general class, artisan won't.
Composer base filename is composer.phar, but you can rename it to composer, or move it to /usr/bin/